# Complexity of reporting solutions to a decision problems

Tags: np

Suppose we have an oracle that tells us whether an instance of the Hamilton cycle problem contains a Hamilton cycle or not.

**Question:**
what is the complexity of e.g. finding the edges constituting to a Hamilton cycle if

- its existence is guaranteed and
- it is known/unknown whether it is unique or not

As I see it, the problem is not a decision problem and thus doesn't belong to NP, but is it "at least as hard as the hardest problems in NP" so that it could be NP-hard?

Comment: To understand it better... you have an oracle that can tell you if you have hamilton cycle and you try to get from it to a possible solution? just take off each edge and ask the oracle if there's a solution.. if still there's just continue and if not return the last and go to the next edge and so on.. that would take you O(E^2), I guess your question is diffrent right?

Comment: @JackRaBeat no, you don't ask the oracle again; the question is as to whether the information about the existence of a Hamilton cycle is of any use in reducing the complexity of finding it. Take for example the degree constraints for the existence of HCs; is it easier to find an HC in graphs that satisfy the constraints? Deleting an edge and checking the constraints again doesn't help here.